# Hide dropdown when mouse leave

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a navigation bar with dropdown as follows.

Can I make it so when my pointer leave the navbar menu and dropdown, the dropdown get hidden? I tried `hover`, `mouseenter`, and `mouseleave` but since I don't really understand the difference and I'm new in this I got stuck.

I already considered about triggering the dropdown display using css `:hover`, but since I have the dropdown placement function they looks like don't work altogether.

Any help appreciated. :)

```js
$(".navbar-menu-each, .submenu-dropdown").hover(function() {
  var menuChoice = $(this).val();
  var menuPosition = $(this).find("a").position();
  var dropdownPosition = menuPosition.left;
  switch(menuChoice) {
    case 0: 
      $(".submenu-dropdown").html("<li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>New Employee Registration</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each submenu-selected'>Employee List</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Rehire</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Without Bank Account</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Without PPh 21</li>");
      break;
    case 1:
      $(".submenu-dropdown").html("<li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Memo Template</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Print Memo</li>");
      break;
    case 2:
      $(".submenu-dropdown").html("<li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Download & Upload</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Send Email</li>");
      break;
    case 3:
      $(".submenu-dropdown").html("<li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Data Approvals</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employment Status Undo</li>");
      break;
    case 4:
      $(".submenu-dropdown").html("<li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Data Report</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Headcount Report</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Recapitulation Report</li>");
      break;
  }
  var dropdownWidth = $(".submenu-dropdown").width();
  var rightEdge = $(document).width();
  if ((dropdownPosition + dropdownWidth) >= (rightEdge - 16)) {
    var adjustRight = rightEdge - dropdownWidth - 16;
     $(".submenu-dropdown").css({"left": adjustRight + "px"});
  }
  else {
    if (dropdownPosition <= 16) {
      $(".submenu-dropdown").css({"left": "16px"});
    }
    else {
      $(".submenu-dropdown").css({"left": dropdownPosition + "px"}); 
    }
  }
  $(".submenu-dropdown").show();
});

$(".navbar-menu-each").click(function() {
  $(".navbar-menu-each").removeClass("menu-on");
  $(this).addClass("menu-on");
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  display: block; 
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 240px;
}

.navbar-logo-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-logo-wrapper img {
  width: 32px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar-top {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar-top-left {

}

.burger-btn-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 16px 0 0;
}

.burger-btn-wrapper i {
  font-size: 16px; 
  color: #333;
  line-height: 60px;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}

.module-name {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #333;
}

.navbar-top-right {

}

.navbar-top-middle {
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
}

.modules-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.modules-icon i {
  font-size: 16px; 
  color: #333;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.navbar-profile {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 0;
}
.navbar-profile img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.profpic-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

.navbar-profpic {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #00c983;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.profile-initial {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.profile-name {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.profile-dropdown {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block; 
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.navbar-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-top-middle img {
  height: 32px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar-menu {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.navbar-menu-list {
  width: 750px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  margin-left: 0;
}

.navbar-menu-each {
  padding-left: 32px;
  padding-right: 32px;
  
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-menu-each:first-child {
  padding-left: 24px; 
}

.navbar-menu-each a {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-on a {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #00c983;
}

.navbar-page-name {
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-top: solid 0.5px #DEF5ED;
  border-bottom: solid 0.5px #DEF5ED;
  background-color: #F0FBF7;
  color: #333;
  padding-left: 24px;
}

.navbar-menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}

.navbar-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.submenu-dropdown {
  background-color: #fff; 
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 106px;
}

.submenu-dropdown-each {
  display: block;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 32px 0 24px;
}

.submenu-dropdown-each:hover {
  background: #f8f8f8; 
}

.submenu-selected {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #00c983;
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .module-name {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .profile-name {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .modules-icon {
    display: none; 
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-logo-wrapper">
    <img class="navbar-tree" src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/7UV_lfX5OBfHxFn5lc3ygK8UTU3z5pivwY9QDSDIOiFemj-DdmDzmwiPvbibaG63IMXz-MmGOs4aH-UqgoT9gw/350">
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-top">
    <div class="navbar-top-left">
      <div class="burger-btn-wrapper">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="module-name">Employee</div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-top-right">
      <div class="modules-icon"><i class="fas fa-th"></i></div>
      <div class="navbar-profile">
        <div class="profpic-wrapper">
          <div class="navbar-profpic">
            <div class="profile-initial">DJ</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-name">Dennis Jonathan</div>
        <div class="profile-dropdown"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-menu">
    <ul class="navbar-menu-list">
      <li class="navbar-menu-each menu-on" value=0><a href="#">Employee Directory</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each" value=1><a href="#">Memo</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each" value=2><a href="#">Bulk Update</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each" value=3><a href="#">Approvals and Undo</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each" value=4><a href="#">Report</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-page-name">
    Employee List
  </div>
</div>
<ul class="submenu-dropdown">
  
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You `html` structure for drop down navigation is kinda wrong, you should put `<ul>` *sub menu*  inside of `<li>` *parent*. already you show sub menu out of parent.

Comment: You are doing this backwards. You should make your drop down appear on hover of the parent nav item. Then when the mouse leave this nav item (or drop down area) the drop down will disappear. You can use pure CSS for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comment:

> You html structure for drop down navigation is kinda wrong, you should
>   put `<ul>` sub menu inside of `<li>` parent. already you show sub menu out
>   of parent.

But with your current `html`, you can `show` menu on `mouseover` and hide it on `mouseleave` like below:

```js
$(".submenu-dropdown").mouseleave(function(){
$(this).hide();
});

$(".navbar-menu-each").mouseover(function() {
  var menuChoice = $(this).val();
  var menuPosition = $(this).find("a").position();
  var dropdownPosition = menuPosition.left;
  switch(menuChoice) {
    case 0: 
      $(".submenu-dropdown").html("<li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>New Employee Registration</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each submenu-selected'>Employee List</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Rehire</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Without Bank Account</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Without PPh 21</li>");
      break;
    case 1:
      $(".submenu-dropdown").html("<li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Memo Template</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Print Memo</li>");
      break;
    case 2:
      $(".submenu-dropdown").html("<li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Download & Upload</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Send Email</li>");
      break;
    case 3:
      $(".submenu-dropdown").html("<li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Data Approvals</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employment Status Undo</li>");
      break;
    case 4:
      $(".submenu-dropdown").html("<li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Data Report</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Headcount Report</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Recapitulation Report</li>");
      break;
  }
  var dropdownWidth = $(".submenu-dropdown").width();
  var rightEdge = $(document).width();
  if ((dropdownPosition + dropdownWidth) >= (rightEdge - 16)) {
    var adjustRight = rightEdge - dropdownWidth - 16;
     $(".submenu-dropdown").css({"left": adjustRight + "px"});
  }
  else {
    if (dropdownPosition <= 16) {
      $(".submenu-dropdown").css({"left": "16px"});
    }
    else {
      $(".submenu-dropdown").css({"left": dropdownPosition + "px"}); 
    }
  }
  $(".submenu-dropdown").show();
});

$(".navbar-menu-each").click(function() {
  $(".navbar-menu-each").removeClass("menu-on");
  $(this).addClass("menu-on");
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  display: block; 
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 240px;
}

.navbar-logo-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-logo-wrapper img {
  width: 32px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar-top {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar-top-left {

}

.burger-btn-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 16px 0 0;
}

.burger-btn-wrapper i {
  font-size: 16px; 
  color: #333;
  line-height: 60px;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}

.module-name {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #333;
}

.navbar-top-right {

}

.navbar-top-middle {
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
}

.modules-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.modules-icon i {
  font-size: 16px; 
  color: #333;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.navbar-profile {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 0;
}
.navbar-profile img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.profpic-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

.navbar-profpic {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #00c983;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.profile-initial {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.profile-name {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.profile-dropdown {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block; 
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.navbar-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-top-middle img {
  height: 32px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar-menu {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.navbar-menu-list {
  width: 750px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  margin-left: 0;
}

.navbar-menu-each {
  padding-left: 32px;
  padding-right: 32px;
  
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-menu-each:first-child {
  padding-left: 24px; 
}

.navbar-menu-each a {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-on a {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #00c983;
}

.navbar-page-name {
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-top: solid 0.5px #DEF5ED;
  border-bottom: solid 0.5px #DEF5ED;
  background-color: #F0FBF7;
  color: #333;
  padding-left: 24px;
}

.navbar-menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}

.navbar-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.submenu-dropdown {
  background-color: #fff; 
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 106px;
}

.submenu-dropdown-each {
  display: block;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 32px 0 24px;
}

.submenu-dropdown-each:hover {
  background: #f8f8f8; 
}

.submenu-selected {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #00c983;
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .module-name {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .profile-name {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .modules-icon {
    display: none; 
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-logo-wrapper">
    <img class="navbar-tree" src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/7UV_lfX5OBfHxFn5lc3ygK8UTU3z5pivwY9QDSDIOiFemj-DdmDzmwiPvbibaG63IMXz-MmGOs4aH-UqgoT9gw/350">
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-top">
    <div class="navbar-top-left">
      <div class="burger-btn-wrapper">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="module-name">Employee</div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-top-right">
      <div class="modules-icon"><i class="fas fa-th"></i></div>
      <div class="navbar-profile">
        <div class="profpic-wrapper">
          <div class="navbar-profpic">
            <div class="profile-initial">DJ</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-name">Dennis Jonathan</div>
        <div class="profile-dropdown"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-menu">
    <ul class="navbar-menu-list">
      <li class="navbar-menu-each menu-on" value=0><a href="#">Employee Directory</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each" value=1><a href="#">Memo</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each" value=2><a href="#">Bulk Update</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each" value=3><a href="#">Approvals and Undo</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each" value=4><a href="#">Report</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-page-name">
    Employee List
  </div>
</div>
<ul class="submenu-dropdown">
  
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is clean and pure `CSS` version with right `html` structure, also you can add your sub menu in your `html` but I keep that part for you:

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yc823403/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can removeClass "show" from ul elements, it´s more clean

This works for me

```
$(".dropdown-menu").mouseleave(function(){  
   $("ul").removeClass("show"); 
});
```